# Compare of std::function with lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

How to compare of std::function with lambda?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    using Type = void( float, int );
    std::function<Type> a;
    auto callback = []( float d, int r )
    {
        cout << d << " " << r << endl;
    };  
    static_assert( std::is_same< Type , decltype( callback ) >::value, "Callbacks should be same!" );


    a(15.7f, 15);   
}
```

Because in case of first parametr of lambda would be `int` - code would compile with 1 warning. How to protect code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the `callback` is not a simple function. A lambda with no captures can decay to function pointer but it isn't a function pointer. It's an instance of a local class.

If you want to ensure a specific function type for a lambda, you can do that by forcing the decay to function pointer type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    using Type = void( float, int );
    std::function<Type> a;
    auto callback = []( float d, int r )
    {
        cout << d << " " << r << endl;
    };  

    // Ensures desired type.
    {
        Type* const func_ptr = callback;   (void) func_ptr;
    }

    a = callback;
    a(15.7f, 15);   
}
```

Comment: Hi, if lambda capture this or some other variable - compare is always false. How to fix that?

Comment: @rikimaru2013: With a capture you can't use decay to function type (there isn't one), so then it starts to get really tricky for the general case. But as I understand it your main goal is just to avoid a **narrowing conversion** for the first argument, that the actual argument is at least a `float`. Then you can replace the checking above with `(void) sizeof( callback( {1.0f}, 0 ), 0 );`.

Comment: I meant, that the *formal* argument is at least a `float`. Sorry. Some pain, unclear or double thinking.