# Compare std::function with callback lambda

Tags: c++

As continue of thread [Compare of std::function with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891977/compare-of-stdfunction-with-lambda)

I have problem with capture `this` to lambda - and compare after that with "correct callback".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void onAppStarted( int, int ) = 0;
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename T>
struct FunctionTypeDeduction;

template<class ClassType, class ReturnType, class... Args>
struct FunctionTypeDeduction< ReturnType( ClassType::* )( Args... ) >
{
    using type                                  = ReturnType( *)( Args... );
    using functorType                           = std::function<ReturnType( Args... ) >;
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SubcribeSystem
{
public:
    using tSomeMethodType                       = FunctionTypeDeduction< decltype( &IFoo::onAppStarted ) >::type;
    using tSomeMethodCallback                   = FunctionTypeDeduction< decltype( &IFoo::onAppStarted ) >::functorType;

public:
    void subribeOnSomeMethod( const tSomeMethodCallback& arr )
    {
        arr( 3, 19 );
    }
};
#define SUBCRIBE_FOR_SOMEMETHOD( eventsObj, lambda )                    \
    do                                                                  \
    {                                                                   \
        SubcribeSystem::tSomeMethodType const func_ptr = lambda;        \
        eventsObj.subribeOnSomeMethod( lambda );                        \
    }                                                                   \
    while(false);                                                       
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Bar
{
public:
    void fn( SubcribeSystem& events )
    {
        auto onAppStart = []( int width, int height )
        {
            cout << width << " " << height << endl;
        };
        auto onAppStart2 = []( bool width, int height )
        {
            cout << width << " " << height << endl;
        };
        auto onAppStart3 = [this]( int width, int height )
        {
            cout << width << " " << height << endl;
            someOtherMethod( width );
        };
        SUBCRIBE_FOR_SOMEMETHOD( events, onAppStart );      // expect all ok    
        //SUBCRIBE_FOR_SOMEMETHOD( events, onAppStart2 );   // expect error cause bool first param  
        SUBCRIBE_FOR_SOMEMETHOD( events, onAppStart3 );     // expect all ok, but not !!!
    }
    void someOtherMethod( int x )
    {
        cout << "processed callback " << x << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    SubcribeSystem sub;
    bar.fn( sub );
}
```

Comment: So is it a followup question?

Answer (score 1):

In your macro you have

```
SubcribeSystem::tSomeMethodType const func_ptr = lambda;
```

Where `SubcribeSystem::tSomeMethodType` is a

```
FunctionTypeDeduction< decltype( &IFoo::onAppStarted ) >::type
```

which is a function pointer.  So you are trying to convert the lambda into a function pointer.  Unfortunately a lambda that captures, which `onAppStart3` does, cannot be converted to a function pointer.

The first two lambdas work as they do not capture so they have an implicit function pointer conversion operator.

Comment: @rikimaru2013 You can store a capturing lambda with a `std::function` like you have with `functorType`.